# How do we center a table in the middle of a webpage

Tags: html

I am doing a layout exercise for homework and I have to align a table to the middle of the webpage; would anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `CSS`. Set a width on a container and left, right margins of auto. Then place your table inside. In this case your div would have an `id` of `container`

```
#container {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```